# Why does the compiler warn about and ignore the call to my function strlen?

Tags: c, function, gcc, call

I tried to call a self-written function without handling its return value. gcc told me at the line of the function call that this would be a **statement with no effect**.
To check whether my function gets called at all, I added some printf statement, but didn't get any output from the program.

Is it possible that gcc simply **ignores the function call**? As far as I know, I never had any problems with such statements.

*So here is the code:*

```
unsigned strlen(char *string)
{
  printf("ignored by gcc");
  unsigned count = 0;
  for(; *string++; count++);
  return count;
}

int main()
{
  char string[] = "something";
  strlen(string);

  return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You've stumbled across a standard C function by the exact same name. Unless you have a good reason otherwise, use that one instead of making your own.

Comment: Call your function something else, gcc uses the built-in `strlen` there.

Comment: The close doesn't seem warranted. This is far more likely to be encountered by other people than the myriad questions here that are about very specific details of one person's code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is perfectly legal to ignore the return value of a function. You probably do it more than 99% of the times you invoke `printf()` (which returns an `int`).

However, as several persons have said in the comments, you called your function `strlen()` after a standard library function. This is illegal according to C99's 7.1.3:2:

> If the program declares or defines an identifier in a context in which
>   it is reserved (other than as allowed by 7.1.4), or defines a reserved
>   identifier as a macro name, the behavior is undefined.

Here the compiler warns unexpectedly, and either calls the standard function instead of yours, or calls no function at all (since it knows **its** `strlen()` is supposed to be without side-effects). This is one of the things undefined behavior can do.

Answer (score 2):

You get the message because gcc's `strlen` is declared with `__attribute__((pure))`, which tells the compiler that it has no side effects, so there's no point in calling it *other* than to use its return value.